# error: expected expression before '%' token scanf(%d, &y);

Tags: c

Im new to C.
I dont understand i have the " in front of the %d

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x,y;
int main(void)
{
        
        printf("Indtast 2 numre du vil bytte rundt på \n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        scanf("%d", &y);
        printf("Dette er dine numre byttet rundt! %d, %d", y, x);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you get rid of that `å` charcater?

Comment: You should go google some/any tutorial in C. That would help better than anyone here can explain.

Comment: Please verify that you show a [mre] here which demonstrates your problem. Ideally make it without special characters, even inside strings, to avoid distraction or hidden problems. If you cannot drop the special character for making a MRE, then you have probably just found the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted here looks fine. However, looking at the title, you seem to have missed double-quotes around %d on line 7. Save the code you just posted, and recompile. Next time, please post the compiler you are using, too.